# Question about double inequalities

Tags: inequality

Assuming $a \in \mathbb{N}^*, b \in \mathbb{N}$, I know the following:
$$0\lt a \lt 9$$
$$0\leq b \lt 9$$
$$b = 7k + a, k\in \mathbb{N}$$
How can I know the double inequality of $k$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put $k$ in terms of $b$ and $a$. Rearranging, we get that $$k = \frac{-a+b}{7}$$

Now, for what values of $a$ and $b$ result in smallest and greatest values?